# How do you access control file information?

Tags: packaging, deb, debian

Is there a way for the postinst, pre, etc. scriptlets to access the information in the Debian control file when installing?

```
e.g. 
   Package: name
   Version: 0.1-1
   Depends: ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the postinst, pre, etc. scriptlets are run in an environment created by dpkg.  The control information are environment variables that the scriptlets can access.

```
e.g.

DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_ARCH=all
DPKG_RUNNING_VERSION=1.16.10
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME=postinst
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE=zip
DPKG_NO_TSTP=yes
DPKG_ADMINDIR=/var/lib/dpkg
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to do it, but the way I like to do it is by using `dpkg`.

Try this:

1. Create a temporary directory ex: `mkdir /tmp/pkg-tmp`
2. Extract control info with dpkg: `dpkg -e ./path/to/file.deb /tmp/pkg-tmp`
3. Check out the control file, it should be in the top level directory: `cat /tmp/pkg-tmp/control`
4. You may want to clean up the temp directory when you are done examining: `rm -rf /tmp/pkg-tmp`

The postinst, preinst, and prerm scripts will be in there too. If there are no files named `preinst`, `postinst`, `postrm`, or `prerm`, then that means none of those scripts are part of the Debian packaging.

Some packages might have all of them, only 1 or 2, or none -- just depends on the package.

If the package is in an APT repository, you can run `apt-get download package-name` to first download the Debian package in the current directory, then run the commands listed above.

I wrote a blog post about [extracting Debian packages and examining the control file, preinstall, postinstall, prerm files](http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/10/13/inspect-extract-contents-debian-packages/) that has more information.

Comment: I think you missed my question.  I'm looking for the post, pre, etc scriplets to access the control information while the installation is going on.